# How to run a simple server and client in python using threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I've got two identical scripts running a client and server on each script respectively,

Script 1:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

# this clients socket is known as conn in server
# ip of the server you want to connect to

HOST = "196.248.183.205"  # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 49000
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))


def boot_server():
    while True:
        server.listen()
        print("starting server...")
        print(f"server binding {HOST, PORT}")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client())
        time.sleep(2)
        thread.start()
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"{addr} is connected")
        message = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(f"message has been received {message}")


def start_client():
    print("starting client...")
    while True:
        clientsocket.connect((HOST, 44355))  # conn to other server ip and port
        clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()


boot_server()
time.sleep(1)
```

Script 2:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

# this clients socket is known as conn in server
# ip of the server you want to connect to

HOST = "196.248.183.205"  # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 44355
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))


def boot_server():
    while True:
        server.listen()
        print("starting server...")
        print(f"server binding {HOST, PORT}")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client())
        time.sleep(2)
        thread.start()
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"{addr} is connected")
        conn.recv(f"connection is successful")


def start_client():
    print("starting client...")
    while True:
        clientsocket.connect((HOST, 49000))  # conn to other server ip and port
        clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()


boot_server()
time.sleep(1)
clientsocket.send("verificationcode".encode("utf-8"))
```

when running the scripts, either script can initiate the connection however id prefer it if the connection could stay open, if i dont run the other script soon enough both scripts fail and the returned message is:
Note the port in the clientsocket does change to 49000 when this script is run first
     `clientsocket.connect((HOST, 44355))  # conn to other server ip and port ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

The issue is that even though both server and client on script 1 do connect to script 2, they dont exchange data from script2 to script1.
Script 2:
`clientsocket.send("verificationcode".encode("utf-8"))`

Im expecting the server in script 1 to receive the data from script 2, but the process doesn't move past
`print("starting client...")`
I am unsure if this is due to the loop created in the function `boot_server()`

Comment: Replace `thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client())` by `thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client)`. Otherwise you start and run the client in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function while creating a thread. You should only pass the function to the `Thread` class. It will call it itself when it has to.

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client())
```

Change the above code to something like this:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=start_client)
```